# Hive OS/Ubuntu How to make package from files (git clone)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, vpn

I have a problem with installation of Windscribe VPN manually through Ubuntu system. I found this files from git: https://github.com/hkuchampudi/Windscribe

I cloned it from git in the folder. I downloaded and installed pacman too but I don't have "makepkg" command. How should I created package in Ubuntu with tar extension (or deb extension) and install my files?

Thanks in advance for directing me what should I do. I only have terminal and don't have display version of Ubuntu.

Comment: `git-build-package` is for your service.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntus package manager is dpkg and apt-get: pacman is the Arch package manager, and Makepkg is a Slackware tool. You need use [apt](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/aptitude/) for Ubuntu

Comment: Before using apt i need to package these files from git and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: In the same package there is such a command as dpkg-deb
`#dpkg-deb --help`
`Usage: dpkg-deb [<option> ...] <command>`

`Commands:
  -b|--build <directory> [<deb>]   Build an archive.
`